# Microsoft WORD add-in generated by generator-office can not load Office object

Tags: word-addins

I have not enough reputation to post pictures, you can see the similar question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/392363/word-add-in-generated-by-generator-office-can-not.html

According to the Microsoft official Office documentation, I tried to use Yeoman's generator-office to generate WORD add-in, and then use npm start to start, but in the Taskpane it always showed "Please sideload your add-in to see app body".

Using the Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview tool, I can see the missing Office objects.So this question has something to do with the version?

But when I visited this add-in via the web page, I can see that the Office object is loaded successfully.

Why is the Office object unsuccessful when accessing this add-in in WORD,and how can I fix this?

Recorded following on May 19th. I tried to executed this example on another computer with Win7 and Office Professional 2016,it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Office 2019 Professional,this problem is solved. I don't know it's the problem of edition, or of activation.